# In which condition can I compare two float variables directly using == in C++?

Tags: c++

I know that comparing two float variables is very tricky. Usually, when the difference of the two float variables is lower than a threshold, we regard these two variables equal. Some cases, however, directly using == is possible, for example,

```
int main()
{   

     float angle = 3.123f;
     if(angle == 3.123f)
     {
         std::cout<<"the same"<<std::endl;
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout<<"different"<<std::endl;
     }

     angle = 13;
     if(angle == 13 )
     {
         std::cout<<"the same"<<std::endl;
     }
     else
     {
         std::cout<<"different"<<std::endl;
     }

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the codes in VC 2010, and it seems `==` is valid in both cases. Therefore, I am asking the question: in which condition we can safely use `==` to compare two variables?

The reason why I asked this question is because there is a function in my project, which looks like the following

```
void fun(int a, int b, float value=180); 

void fun(int a, int b, float value)
{
   if(value == 180)
   {
       // do something
   }
   else
   {
        // do something
   }
}
```

Basically, in the `fun` function, there is a default float variable as a function parameter. In the function implementation, we will check whether we are using the default setting, and if it is, special treatment will be performed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All integers up to 2^24 are exactly representable as `float`s, so there won't be any trouble here.

The major reason not to use floating point equality is because of imprecise floating point operations -- `(180 / 7) * 7` may or may not exactly equal 180. However, if it's just being passed as a default argument, you're entirely safe.

If you're particularly concerned, instead of a default argument, just put in a two-argument overload which handles the default case.

Comment: The overload should just call the content of the `if(value == 180)` branch, else there would be no benefit over defaulting the third parameter.

Comment: I guess this is assuming IEEE 754 or does you believe this applies more generally?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour It applies to any C++-standard floating point type with a 23-bit mantissa.

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` when you want what it's meant to do:  exact equality comparison.  It's generally not appropriate to check for exact equality on the result of an inexact calculation that may have rounding error, but if you want to treat a certain (exact) value as a special case, with the expectation that callers will pass that (exact) value in order to trigger the special case, that's OK.

It also makes sense to check for exact values that make a calculation much simpler:  for example, if you're implementing a cosine function, you could check whether the argument equals (exactly) 0 and return (exactly) 1, skipping the more sophisticated math to calculate the cosine in the general case.  Note that in this case you're returning the same value that the more sophisticated computation *would* have produced, so callers won't see strange behavior depending on whether they pass exactly 0 or something very close to 0:  they'll just get exactly 1 or something very close to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, equality means that the exact value you are comparing against has been assigned to the variable before. What makes things tricky is not the comparison but the maths behind floats. If you assign 180 t a float and compare it against 180, it will always yield true. The same holds for assigning 4.15 and comparing against 4.15 and so on. The rounding errors come into play only if you do calculations and if the values involved are not exactly representable by the binary format used for floats.

However, in your case thats not interesting, since you only want to distinguish between defaulted and non-defaulted. You should use two functions for that case and overload them:

```
void fun(int a, int b)
{
  // do the default-something
}

void fun(int a, int b, float value)
{
  // do the else-something
}
```

The behavior will however differ in the case where your non-defaulted input is exaclty `180f` by accident.

Comment: With respect to 4.15 (which I assume does not have an exact representation as a binary float): Is there a possiblity that it be stored or passed through a hardware register, e.g. when passing it as a paramete to a function, so that the comparison would fail even without any explicit conversion or calculation? (I'd assume that values which have an exact representation in the smallest floating type involved -- like the OP's 180 -- would not suffer hidden value changes from such mechanisms.)

Answer (score 0):

For sufficiently small integers, you should be pretty safe.

But as soon as the value you're comparing has been through any kind of processing or conversion, all bets are off.

It's not a very good idea.

Consider using a `NaN`, infinity, or something "harder".